# Смена сайта при задании вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-отклонено

Хотелось бы иметь возможность оперативной смены сайта при задании вопроса. Например, хотел задать вопрос на Мете, но случайно начал его писать на основном сайте. Заметил, когда дело уже дошло до установки меток.

По большому счету проблема решается через copy-past заголовка и тела вопроса, но, возможно, было бы неплохо иметь функционал быстрой смены сайта размещения вопроса до его постинга.

Comment: Достаточно сомнительная фича. Редкая потребность при больших (возможно) затратах на изменение в движке.

Comment: @Other я не думаю, что это сложно реализовать, но вопрос в необходимости действительно спорный, т.к. проблему по сути можно обойти парой-тройкой копи-паст.

Comment: Понятия не имею как устроен движок, так что сказать "Сложно ли?" я не могу. Но, возможно, если API ко всем сайтам похожий, то может и легко - список сайтов на странице и выбор нужного в API на сервере.

Comment: С большой вероятностью, не будет реализовано. Если вы считаете, что данный функционал вам крайне нужен, возможно стоит сделать расширение к вашему обозревателю. На сколько я знаю, каким–то хитрым образом содержимое [вопроса можно передавать через параметры ссылки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81&tags=java,c).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky про параметры интересно. Возьму на заметку. Ещё и черновик при этом подхватывается, если был сохранен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хотя предложение и отклонено здесь. Подобный функционал реализован в **официальном** приложении Stack Exchange для iOS:

> [image: выбор сайта]

Таким образом, некоторые разработчики посчитали его вполне подходящим.

Comment: Потому что на десктопе существует простой обходной путь через копи-паст, а на iOS это не так-то и просто сделать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov точно так же: выбрать всё - скопировать.