# Причина удаления вопроса Духом

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, удаление-вопросов

На [странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/109089) проверки вопроса на закрытие присутствует, как мне кажется, некоторая внутренняя для сайта информация, содержащая текст `RemovedAbandonedClosed`. Ну, или по-крайней мере нуждающаяся в переводе:

[image: RemovedAbandonedClosed]

Ещё один [удалённый вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3858/176217), но по другой причине, так же содержит подобное описание `RemoveDeadQuestion`:

[image: RemoveDeadQuestion]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В текущем дизайне эти строки уже не просачиваются в пользовательский интерфейс:

> [image: Сообщение удалено]

Comment: Что ж. Всего 4 года прошло (¬‿¬ )