# RemoveDeadQuestions не переведено

Tags: дефект, локализация, удаление-вопросов

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/744295/15479

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не переводибельно. Как-то уже публиковал нечто подобное. Надо поискать только.

Comment: @alexolut https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3868/15479