# Конкурс завершен с выбранным %username% ответил участником

Tags: дефект, локализация, конкурс

Что-то с этой фразой явно не так ([вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/743944/revisions)):

> [image: картинка]

> **Конкурс завершен** с выбранным [%username% ответил](/#) участником [%username%](/#)

Подразумевалось «с выбранным ответом от %username%» или как?

Comment: (целых три минуты сидел думал, почему метка «дефект» не имеет свой собственный цвет, пока не дошло, что мимо меты промахнулся)

Comment: Была [идейка о смене сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3858/176217) для подобных случаев.

Comment: @älёxölüt я тут кстати подумал, что если бы метовые теги типа «дефект» были заблокированы на основном сайте, то я бы не промахнулся сайтом